# Check if namespace declared correctly

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

When my folder and file structure is like this:

```
project-folder
└── src
    └── App
        └── Something
            └── MyClass.php
```

I want to get error or warning when I use wrong namespace in *MyClass.php* file:

```php
<?php

// should be namespace App\Something;
namespace App\Something2; // this line should give me error or warning
```

My Eclipse PDT setup can do this but I cannot find this feature on vscode.

I installed these extensions:

- PHP Intelephense
- PHP Namespace Resolver
- PHP Sniffer

Comment: you can always write your on extension with a Diagnostic provider

Comment: @rioV8 Is there any extension available doing that? Because if not, I have to learn how to write vscode extensions.